# Flutter - Capture and save image in different aspect ratios (4:3)

Tags: android, flutter, camera, flutter-dependencies

I wanted to preview and save a photo in a 4:3 aspect ratio, which is the standard and has the maximum resolution.

The [camera plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/camera) doesn't support changing the photo aspect ratio.

The [Camera awesome](https://pub.dev/packages/camerawesome) plugin also has similar issues I think.

The [adv_camera](https://pub.dev/packages/adv_camera) plugin has all the features but it doesn't support streaming images to run some AI-based analysis.

I'm not asking about the aspect ratio of the preview. The Aspect Ratio of the photo is saved is the problem.

Is there any way to get this done?

Answer (score 1):

https://pub.dev/packages/image

```dart
var image = decodeImage(imageBytes);
image = copyResize(image, width: image.width, height: (image.width * 0.75).toInt());
imageBytes = encodePng(image); // encodeJpg/...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue and I don't see a good solution.

I can offer 2 solutions that are both not optimal.

1. Use image_picker
2. Take the pictures in 16:9 and then crop them

Both more workarounds than solutions.